# Export shapefile using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, export

I am trying to export selected feature using PyQGIS.

Till now I have tried these codes. After using this I can select feature but don't know how to export selected feature to new shapefile.

```py
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
AllLayers = canvas.layers()
for i in AllLayers:
    it = i.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(u'"Country" = \'India\''))
    i.setSelectedFeatures([f.id() for f in it])
    print "Filter Applied"
```

Have tried this code: but this is just creating a duplicate of source file (I need selected only)

```py
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(i, r"C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\NewFile.shp", "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
```

If anybody knows how can I export shapefile using PyQGIS?

Comment: did you carfully read documentation about QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat? http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a3e9189e41a9b55820463da634da85d33

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Luigi suggests, you can have a look at the API documentation, specifically to [QgsVectorFileWriter::writeAsVectorFormat](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a3e9189e41a9b55820463da634da85d33), and realize you're just missing one parameter (from the docs):

```
bool onlySelected = false,
```

It says that the parameter `onlySelected` is of type boolean and is false by default. This parameter is right after the driver name. So, calling the function this way:

```
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(i,r"C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\NewFile.shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile", True)
```

will export only the selected features from your layer.