# Dropping z dimension programmatically

Tags: qgis, python, dimensions

It seems there is no geoalgorithm to drop z values in the QGIS processing toolbox. Can this be done programmatically using the Python console? At the moment I have to save the layer with unchecked 'Include z-dimension' checkbox (non automatic geometry type):

[image]

Comment: You could use the QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat method (see for instance http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153309/qgis-export-shapefile-using-pyqgis/153318#153318 ). There is a includeZ parameter, but you won't need to pass it to the function because it's False by default.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For future reference - QGIS 3 includes a drop z value processing algorithm

Answer (score 5):

Specifically, the QGIS 3 tool is called **`Drop m/z values`**.  It's in the Processing Toolbox, under Vector Geometry.  The documentation is here:

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisdropmzvalues

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i convert a QgsGeometry (geom) of type PolygonZ to a Polygon in the console:

```
new_geom = QgsGeometry().fromPolygonXY(geom.asPolygon())
```

It is some kind of workaround since there is no dedicated method for that. So i dont know if there are better ways to do it. Using the processing tool as recommended in the other answers would be the correct way if you want to convert a whole layer i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ogr2ogr with `-dim XY` flag:

> Force the coordinate dimension

See: https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-dim