# GEOS_ERROR ParseException Unknown type MULTILINESTRINGZM

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, qgis-processing, geos

i have a `MULTILINESTRING` layer in posgis table and I wand to add new features from export layer using some algorithm in QGIS processing and Python but the export layer from QGIS processing has type `MULTILINESTRINGZM` and  I take this error :

```
GEOS_ERROR: ParseException: Unknown type: 'MULTILINESTRINGZM'
```

here the add features code :

```
geom=str(f1.geometry().asWkt())
```

Any idea how to fix this conversion error ?

Comment: Perhaps with convertTo https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Abstract/QgsAbstractGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsAbstractGeometry.convertTo.

Comment: @user30184 can you show how to use convertTo in pyqgis ?

Comment: @user30184 because i use this     `rep=QgsVectorLayer(c_repr, "rep")` and 
    `rep.convertTo(QgsWkbTypes.MultiLineString)` but not working

Comment: I made probably a bad guess. Maybe something like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232002/dropping-z-dimension-programmatically works for you.

Comment: @user30184 thank you for help work now.Drop m/z values fix my problem thanx

Comment: You could write your solution as an answer.

Comment: @user30184 i use Drop m/z values algorithm from QGIS processing tool