# Selecting features from one layer into new layer based on IDs using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, layers, select

I'm completely new to PYQGIS. I'm pretty handy with MapBasic in MapInfo and was wondering how I would 'translate' this command from SQL select into Python (hope that makes sense)

Essentially, I have a layer with multiple objects - but I only want to select and extract the objects which have an id like %ABC% into a separate layer.

In MapBasic I would:

```
Select * from *examplelayer* where id Like "%ABC%" into *ABC*
```

where '**id**' is a field I want to search in the table/layer '**examplelayer**', id Like "%ABC%" meaning that any id's containing ABC will be selected into a new table/map layer named "ABC"

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Can you show more of your python code so we can see where you're up to. Do you have a *list* of IDs? If so layer.setSelectedFeatures([ID,ID,ID...]) then export the selected, this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153309/qgis-export-shapefile-using-pyqgis might help point you in the right direction.