# Exporting selected features to shapefile PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to develop a script to export selected features on a layer to enable some automation.

So far I have used this formula to import a layer and run a query. This ends up with features being selected on the layer.

[image: import script]

See result:

[image: selected features]

All good so far.

I now try to use the below script, found in a previous similar question:
[QGIS Export Shapefile using PyQgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153309/qgis-export-shapefile-using-pyqgis)

It worked for the users in the post, however this returns the following error for me:

[image: export error]

I am quite new to Python so am not quite sure what's wrong. It is saying name 'i' is not defined, but I'm not sure what 'i' is trying to refer to?

I'm using QGIS 2.18.20.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `i` in the post you linked to was referencing all layers that were loaded. So the code was iterating through each layer and saving their selected features.

Since you're only interested in one layer, replace `i` with `layer` and add the boolean selection parameter [`onlySelected`](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#ab566ed2016352c37d9a4a6900614eac2):

```
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, 'C:/Datasets/South Oxfordshire Clipped LR INSPIRE.shp', "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile", onlySelected=True)
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you. My next task is to create a loop for this to run through 348 individually named shapefiles. However I will try this myself first before asking for help!

Comment: @JClarkson - Most welcome, glad it helped and good luck :)

Comment: FYI in QGIS 3.8 I was getting "TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(): arguments did not match any overloaded call: ... " - I had to replace the 'None' with layer.crs so the new format is -- `_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, 'd:/junk/test.shp', "UTF-8", layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile", onlySelected=True)`

Comment: @GeorgeC - Good to know, thanks :)